# Route a specific host to different gateway

Tags: route, iproute

I have a basic Ubuntu 18.04 setup where the computer has two interfaces - one for internal (enp4s0) and one that heads to the internet (enp5s0).  On the internet interface I successfully have a VPN (tun0) in place, which takes over all outbound traffic to enp5s0 so that internet traffic is protected by the VPN.

What I am trying work out is - how do I get one host inside my network (for example 192.168.1.220) to stay outside of the VPN and head out through enp5s0. I don't want it to be inside the VPN.

Can anyone advise on what I need to do to my routes?  I believe I have to set up a table via iproute2 but I've had no luck getting it to work.

**Route Table (VPN enabled)**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.8.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
45.248.79.198   _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp5s0
128.0.0.0       10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

**Route Table (VPN disabled)**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

**UFW Rule (to get LAN traffic to VPN)**

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: When the VPN is down and I do a trace from 192.168.1.220 I get:

   Tracing route to www.google.com [172.217.25.132] over a maximum of 30 hops:

    1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  BOB [192.168.1.100]
    2     1 ms     4 ms     3 ms  SAGEMCOM [192.168.8.1]

Which is the correct hop, and what I'm trying to force even when the VPN is up.

Answer (score 2):

You need [policy routing](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html), so something along the lines of

```
ip route add table 250 default dev enp5s0
ip rule add from 192.168.1.220 table 250
```

I'm not sure where `_gateway` points to, you may have to add `via a.b.c.d` in the first line. Also, I'd recommend to use the newer `ip route` over the older `route`.

Comment: Gateway points to the enp5s0 interface (192.168.8.2), which then heads out to the DSL modem (192.168.8.1) so I tried doing the following to no avail:

**route changes**
    $ sudo ip route add table 250 192.168.8.1 dev enp5s0
    $ sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.220 table 250

** results**
$ ip route show all
default via 192.168.8.1 dev enp5s0 onlink

A tracert from 192.168.1.220 still shows the traffic going via tun0 though, not enp5s0.

Comment: Use `ip route show table 250` to verify route, also try `ip route add table 250 default via 192.168.8.2 dev enp5s0` as already mentioned. Veryify with `ip route get a.b.c.d from 192.168.1.220 iif enp4s0` that the rules work.

Comment: yes all routes on main table for enp5s0 have to be duplicated on table 250 (ok except the non-needed route to vpn)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not misunderstanding you, but: Table 250 should **only** contain the new default route for 192.168.1.220. If **should not** contain all the other routes in the main table. If it does, of course all traffic will go again through tun0.

Comment: ok it's not needed *in this case* to duplicate all routes with enp5s0 (as long as via 192.168.8.1 is added) I was wrong.

Comment: @dirkt If I run ip route show table 250 the result I get is:  


default via 192.168.8.2 dev enp5s0


If I do a trace from 192.168.1.220 the first hop is still the VPN, it's like something is overriding what I am requesting.


Any ideas?

Comment: @dirkt Any other ideas? (sorry, not sure if tagging you has worked!)

Comment: It also says: 
ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.220 iif enp4s0
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.220 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0
    cache iif enp4s0

Comment: If `ip route get` shows the wrong route, then either the `rule` is screwed up and it doesn't use the correct table, or their are other rules that override this rule, or the table contains this route for some reason. So use `ip ...` to inspect, and debug via modifying the rules/tables and narrow down where the hangup is.

Comment: Running routel I get the below, which shows the rule added (250) but it looks like the second rule (inserted by the VPN) steals the traffic somehow.  Totally has me stumped.

         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
        default        192.168.8.1                                   enp5s0 250
        0.0.0.0 1         10.8.8.1                                     tun0
        default        192.168.8.1                                   enp5s0

Comment: I can't debug your configuration if all you give me are snippets. (And you really should debug it yourself, remote debugging like this is a PITA). Please edit question with the **complete** output of `ip route show`, `ip route show table 250`, and `ip rule list`, properly formatted. Output of `route` is useless, because it doesn't take policy routing into account.

Comment: I can't get the formatting here to work, which is part of the issue.


I have it now working, the commands used are:


ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 table novpn
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 table novpn
ip rule add from 192.168.1.220 table novpn
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.210-192.168.1.220 -o enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: Comments are not meant for additional information, you are supposed to **edit** the question. That's why there's no formatting in comments. If it's just a routing issue, you shouldn't need to NAT. If you need to NAT, you didn't explain that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It always takes some puzzling to get a network layout from these tables. As I see it:

- you have two physical interfaces, enp4s0 and enp5s0
- enp4s0 is directly connected to 192.168.1.0/24
- enp5s0 is directly connected t0 192.168.8.0/24
- your host `_gateway` is on 192.168.8.0/24
- your tunnel endpoint is 45.248.79.198

The routing-table you provide has something strange:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0    
128.0.0.0       10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

You are splitting the Internet in two halves, both go through tun0.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
```

Your default-gateway is still `_gateway`

I would have expected the routing-tabel to look like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
45.248.79.198   _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp5s0    
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
```

To go to your question: 192.168.1.220 is on a direct connected network. It will therefore not to a gateway, if it is pure a routing issue.

Comment: The "splitting the internet in two halves" is a standard trick used by many VPN applications to keep the default rule, but supply a new "default" rule that's more specific and will overwrite the old default rule.

Comment: this splitting allows to be 100% sure to override the "usual" default route even if its metric is 0 (as seen here) without having to delete it and without risking an other tool (network manager etc) replaces the vpn's default route with the former default